# CSV file in Python to create graph and average degree

Tags: python, csv, networkx

I have a CSV file with two columns assigned as nodes interacting with each other, now I want to call this file in Python to create a graph and to find out the average degree of each node.

My data looks like:

[image]

Comment: whoa, more effort needed: provide data, details, and show us what you've done up to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time *at least* put your data in text form.

Here is the data I used.

```
column1  column2
abc      def
abc      ghi
jkl      <empty>
```

In the code below I read the file `some_data.csv` with the `csv` package.
I set the delimiter in the `csv.reader` command with `delimiter=' '`.
In the same command I used `skipinitialspace=True` to ignore extra spaces.

If both nodes are present I add the edge to the graph with `add_edge`, else I only add the first node with `add_node`.
You could add another `elif` to test if the first node is `<empty>`.

```
import networkx as nx
import csv

G = nx.Graph()

with open('some_data.csv') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        next(csv_reader, None)  # skip header
        for row in csv_reader:
            # check if second node is empty
            if row[1] == '<empty>':
                G.add_node(row[0])
            # else assume both nodes are present
            else:
                G.add_edge(row[0], row[1])
```

You can get the individual nodes with [`nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html).
To get their degrees you can use [`degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.degree.html).

```
for node in G.nodes():
    print(node, 'has a degree of', G.degree(node))
```

Output:

```
jkl has a degree of 0
def has a degree of 1
ghi has a degree of 1
abc has a degree of 2
```